# Different solving method for Excel Formula and WorksheetFunction formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using an `application.worksheetfunction.countifs` in one of my codes but it seems to have suddenly stopped working.  I typed the code into excel in the same format and it works as it should but the VBA code does not.

```
=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$2582,  ">0", $E$2:$E$2582, E3, $L$2:$L$2582, L3, $B$2:$B$2582, B3, $T$2:$T$2582, "<=" & T3, $U$2:$U$2582, "<=" & U3)
```

VBA code used in Macro:

```
For Each Cell In Range("R2:R" & LastRow)
    If Cell.Offset(0, -3) = "" Then
    Cell.Value = ""
    Else: Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("D2:D" &
          LastRow), ">" & 0, Range("E2:E" & LastRow), Cell.Offset(0, -13), 
          Range("L2:L" & LastRow), Cell.Offset(0, -6), Range("B2:B" & 
          LastRow), Cell.Offset(0, -16), Range("T2:T" & LastRow), "<=" & 
          Cell.Offset(0, 2), Range("U2:U" & LastRow), "<=" & Cell.Offset(0,
          3))
    End If
Next Cell
```

I also tried the first search criteria as `">0"` but that did not change the output at all.

I am utterly baffled on what I am doing wrong because it was working one moment, then suddenly it only counting some cells according to the formula the next minute.

And yes, I know I did not include the parameter for blank cells in the excel code, but that isn't what is causing the code problems.

Please help.

Comment: I think you need to provide some more information about what you may have changed, either in the code or in the spreadsheet.  Do you really expect us to believe that your computer "just suddenly" changed the way it executes your code?

Comment: If you're using VBA with a loop anyway, why wouldn't you just program it using if statements and a variable to count?

Comment: Are those new lines of code without an underscore `_` to continue the line?

Comment: The value of `LastRow` is equivalent to 2582.  Also, I took out the underscores in the code to avoid confusion and to make the code easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the VBA code was having a hard time reading the amount of decimal places in the search criteria.  Therefore, it was having difficulty comparing two infinitely rounded numbers against one another.  I am not sure why the Excel formula worked, but the VBA did not, however, a simple `Round()` code before the cells in my search criteria fixed the problem.  Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction...` with `Cell.Formula =` and building a string representing the desired formula.  You've already stated that the formula, when typed in, produces the correct results.  Replicating that formula via code will also produce the correct result.

`Application.WorksheetFunction` only returns the **result** of the function, and without inspecting your code further, you can't see how this formula differs from the one that works.

Comment: This is the code I used and it worked perfectly.  `Sheets("LoadTables_Blanks").Range("R2").Formula = "=CountIfs($D$2:$D$" & LastRow & ", "">0"", $E$2:$E$" & LastRow & ", E2, $L$2:$L$" & LastRow & ", L2, $B$2:$B$" & LastRow & ", B2, $T$2:$T$" & LastRow & ", ""<="" & T2, $U$2:$U$" & LastRow & ", ""<="" & U2)"
Range("R2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R7"), Type:=xlFillDefault` However, I would rather use `WorksheetFunction.Countifs` so that the code runs quicker.  I seriously cannot see where my issue is.

Comment: If you found an answer helpful, it's polite to upvote and/or accept.  It's unreasonable to expect people who cannot see your original spreadsheet, to virtually look over your shoulder and evaluate your formulas.